# JavaScript chaining functions, last methods returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, scope, chain

My app receives a base64 encoded value that is also encrypted. The data can come in a few different ways so I wanted to create chain-able methods to keep the code clean and modular.

I want to be able write: decryptionChain.decodeBase64(b64Value).stringToBuffer().finallyDecrypt();

When I run the code, the last property method "finallyDecrypt" returns as undefined.

Why is the "finallyDecrypt" method coming back as undefined? The rest all works and if I run ecryptionChain.decodeBase64(b64Value).stringToBuffer() I get back the Buffer I expect.  It is only when the finallyDecrypt is chained in that I error out.

Here is the code:

```
   function decrypt(encrypted) {
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, password, iv);
    decipher.setAuthTag(encrypted.tag);
    var dec = decipher.update(encrypted.content, 'hex', 'utf8');
    dec += decipher.final('utf8');
    return dec;
}

var decryptionChain = {

    currentValue:"",

    decodeBase64: function (encryptedValue){
        this.currentValue = new Buffer(encryptedValue.toString(), "base64");
        return this;
    },

    stringToBuffer: function() {
        if (this.currentValue) {
            myBuffer = JSON.parse(this.currentValue, function (key, value) {
                 return value && value.type === 'Buffer'
                    ? new Buffer(value.data)
                    : value;

            });

        }
        return myBuffer;
    },

    finallyDecrypt : function(myBuffer){
        if(myBuffer){
        decrypt(myBuffer);
        }
        return this;

    }
};
```

Comment: Please don't do that. With your proposed design, one could as easily call `decryptChain.stringToBuffer().decodeBase64(b64Value)` or `decryptChain.finallyDecrypt().finallyDecrypt()` which just doesn't make sense. Make each method return a different object.

Comment: Hmmm based on given info that should be working. Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example?

Comment: Its node.js, Fiddle wont support it. Not sure if there is a Fiddle like service for node. Quick Google search didn't turn anything up that actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

From the code shown, I have spotted some issues.First:

`decryptionChain` != `decryptChain` If its just a typo in the question, then disregard, if its not, please reffer to that.

Please, use the [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) to decrease possibilities of scope errors, or "scoped variables" being left behind.

Second, dont use a [string as a Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean).

Third, you seem to have an issue with the `return value && value.type === 'Buffer' ? new Buffer(value.data) : value;`, please assign before returning (not necessary, but simpler)